# What's the name of the stick or vertical line that appears in front of the characters as you type?

Tags: windows-10

Everyone knows the stick that you use to know where you will write when writing in computer.
But does anyone know the name of it?
I need to make a research about it, but I don't know how to call it. I tried many ways to search it like "The stick appears when you start to write" but they didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

It's called a **[caret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_navigation)**
When it's an arrow it's a [cursor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_(user_interface)), when it's a vertical line | in text editing, it's a caret. A caret is also a type of cursor & some people still refer to the vertical line as a cursor.

It is difficult to google even if you know what it's called, because this symbol ^ is also called a [caret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret).

Comment: Thanks dude!!
I really searched it too much.

Comment: If you are in overwrite mode, the vertical line becomes a rectangle but it is still called a caret.

Comment: May also be known as an “insertion point” in some documentation.